# желание vs. пожелание

Tags: значения, словоупотребление

What is the exact difference between those two words an especially when can ***пожелание*** be used and the other one not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"желание" is **wish, desire** in a sense that you usually asssociate with the word: something you want to happen/to have. When a djihn or a fairy grants a wish, it is usually "желание".

"Пожелание" is something you *wish someone*. Also a very popular word for ***suggestions ,request, wish***, *often  for improvements* (a stock phrase "ваши пожелания" ~ "any suggestions?"):

- Наши наилучшие пожелания! = Our best wishes!
- Они учли наши пожелания относительно длины текста ~ They have taken our wishes/suggestions concerning the length of the text into account.